# How to do a Check for every element in the list?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I know how to do a Check for the list in general:

```
lst = {"0/0", "1/25", "1/36", "1/49"}

Quiet[Check[StringReplace[lst, "0/0" -> Missing["Unavailable"]] // ToExpression, _, ToExpression::notstrbox], ToExpression::notstrbox]
```

But I need to to the check that for each element, so to have a result like:

```
{Missing["Unavailable"], 1/25, 1/36, 1/49}
```

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply `lst /. {"0/0" :> Missing["Unavailable"]}` ?

Comment: How about `myfun[x_] := If[x == "0/0", Missing["Unavailable"], ToExpression[x]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I need to do ToExpression after

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think he wants numerical out puts as 1/25 instead of "1/25". In your case, the replacement rule only replaces the "0/0" case, but does not convert the strings to numerical values?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part.  Reopened.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Please post your answer.

Comment: @SuTron How about the function `myfun` (see above) and then use `Map[myfun, lst]`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was editing my answer just before it was closed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
myfun[x_] := If[x == "0/0", Missing["Unavailable"], ToExpression[x]]
Map[myfun, lst]
```

> {Missing["Unavailable"], 1/25, 1/36, 1/49}

Answer (score 3):

Possibly you would be pleased with an alternative approach:

```
lst = {"0/0", "1/25", "1/36", "1/49"};

Quiet @ ToExpression @ lst /. Indeterminate -> Missing["Unavailable"]
```

> ```
> {Missing["Unavailable"], 1/25, 1/36, 1/49}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = {"0/0", "1/25", "1/36", "1/49"};
```

Temporarily change the definition of `Indeterminate` to `Missing["NotAvailable"]`:

```
Block[{Indeterminate = Missing["NotAvailable"]}, Quiet@ToExpression@lst]
```

> `{Missing["NotAvailable"], 1/25, 1/36, 1/49}`